# sym Invalid Argument Type

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add total row after calculating count and proportion. I have created a function for the same but it's returning error when passing `!!sym(group_var)`

```
freq_table <- function(df, group_var) {
      
      group_var2 <- !!sym(group_var)
      
      df %>%
        group_by_at(group_var) %>%
        summarise(n = n()) %>%
        mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
        ungroup %>%
        bind_rows(., data.frame(
          group_var2 := "Grand Total",
          sapply(. %>% dplyr::select_if(is.numeric),
                 function(x) sum(x, na.rm = T)) %>% t()
        ))
      
    }
    
    freq_table(iris, group_var = "Species")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could do this more easily with `adorn_totals`

```
freq_table <- function(df, group_var) {
  df %>%
     dplyr::group_by(across(all_of(group_var))) %>%
     dplyr::summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
     dplyr::mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
     janitor::adorn_totals(name = "Grand Total")     
  
}
```

-testing

```
freq_table(iris, group_var = "Species")
#     Species   n      freq
#      setosa  50 0.3333333
#  versicolor  50 0.3333333
#   virginica  50 0.3333333
# Grand Total 150 1.0000000
```

---

The `!!` should be used within the tidyverse functions.  Also, here we don't need the `sym` or `!!` as the OP is using `group_by_at` which can take a string, then the assignment (`:=`), the lhs can be string.  Modified the `bind_rows` with the looping by `sapply` and `t`ranspose as this returns a `matrix`.  We can make use of `summarise` with `across` to loop over the `numeric` columns, and add a new row at the bottom with `add_row`

```
freq_table <- function(df, group_var) {     
  
    df %>%
       group_by_at(all_of(group_var)) %>%
       summarise(n = n()) %>%
       mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
       ungroup %>%
       add_row(
      !!group_var := "Grand Total",
                  {.} %>% 
            summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE)))          
  
  }
```

-testing

```
freq_table(iris, group_var = "Species")
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Species         n  freq
#  <chr>       <int> <dbl>
#1 setosa         50 0.333
#2 versicolor     50 0.333
#3 virginica      50 0.333
#4 Grand Total   150 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Total values should be under columns n and freq rather than additional two columns.